# Custom serialization to space-delimited string with only values and no keys

Tags: c#, serialization

I'm writing a client for the MSN Messenger protocol and I have classes which represent commands sent to and from a server

These examples are simplified

```
class AddUserCommand {
    public int TransactionId { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
}

class SendMessageCommand {
    public int TransactionId { get; set; }
    public string Recipient { get; set; }
    public string DeliveryMethod { get; set; }
    public int MessageLength { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible using the classes already available in the .NET framework to serialize these commands into very simple space-delimited strings to be sent over a socket?

eg..

```
 AddUserCommand becomes
 ADD 3 bob@bob.com

 SendMessageCommand becomes
 MSG 2 bob@bob.com OFFLINE 28
 Hello bob how are you doing?
```

The problem is that all serialization classes I've seen/used use key value pairs, where as I want the key to be implied by the position of the argument in the string.

Comment: I don't know if this will help you at all, but you may want to look into "SharpSerializer".  You can install it into your project by going to Project->ManageNuGet Packages->Search for "SharpSerializer".  Its an excellent tool for serializing custom types, and provides ways to easily implement custom serialization which it seems you will need.  Here's a link to the website http://www.sharpserializer.com/en/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you will have to write your own or use a library which already speaks this protocol.

You will need to write the code which converts these objects to and from strings. You would not use built-in interfaces. Why? Because there is nothing that helps you with this. You might use an interface, but it will likely be one you write yourself. Obviously you have the option to use various utility classes such as `TextWriter` if you wish, but these are just data streams, not serialization. The issue is that you are trying to conform to a non-standardized format defined by an external application. Why would the .NET framework have anything to do with MSN Messenger?

There may be generalized serialization libraries you could use, but IMO you're better off writing your own because these libraries are going to result in more complicated code than doing it yourself. Most of them would be based on key-value pairs, and thus not well-suited. Also, this is not a hard problem to solve with your own code.

Comment: Why would the .NET framework had anything to do with MSN Messenger? I don't know, who ever said that? .. The MSN protocol uses a unique means of serialization, but even still I thought there was a possibility that the .NET framework might have serialization classes which could be used, and that's what I was asking about.

Comment: Well it does not, and my point is that it does not make sense for it to do so. .NET is a framework for writing many kinds of programs, not a communications library for MSN Messenger. Few applications based on .NET would benefit from such functionality being included in the core framework. This is why people write libraries instead.

Comment: Thank you for your answer it is indeed helpful. In your opinion, does the code to serialize/deserialize belong in the command classes themselves, or in a special Serializer/Deserializer class which looks at the type and arranges the variables into a string of arguments?

Comment: It could go either way. Is this the only format into which you will be serializing these messages? If so, I personally would make the messages implement an interface which defines two functions for serializing and deserializing.

Comment: Really? it doesn't make sense for the .NET framework to support different varieties of serialization? I think you're wrong there. While MSNP is unique, I'm sure it's not unheard of to do things that way. IRC uses a similar protocol if I remember correctly. I'm not arguing that the .NET framework should have an understanding of a unique protocol used by one service, I was simply asking if the .NET framework could be used to "talk" protocols like MSNP.

Comment: One more question if you don't mind.. if I put the two functions for serializing and deserializing on the class itself, which class is actually responsible for recognizing the type of class which is being deserialized to? I suppose that would be a sort-of CommandReader class?

Comment: Sure it can be, but why would this be in the core? There are thousands of network protocols out there. Should every single one be included in the framework? Do you want to download a several gigabyte installer for it? No one does this. This is why most languages have a library mechanism which allows someone else to write a library which can be packaged separately for use by those who need that functionality.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22414/discussion-between-dark-falcon-and-nopygod)

Comment: Again I think you're misunderstanding what I'm saying. In the .NET framework there are classes which perform general tasks. I was hoping the MSNP protocol was general enough that some .NET framework classes would be useful.